# Binning and plotting (Hist) data from a (n,2) matrix

Tags: matlab, plot, histogram, bin

I (mostly) have a prototype script to achieve what I want, but I'm not programmer (yet), and what I wrote is very cumbersome.  I could use some help fitting this into a package that is amenable to something more than 10 bins (see below).  While we're at it, I also would love to know how to assign different colors to each series.

Briefly, I've got a (n,2) matrix --where n is 20,000 to 40,000) that consists of data for two variables.    Typically, I make a scatterplot (or density plot) with each variable on an axis.  Now, I want to slice up the data (err, divide the data into bins) along the x axis and plot a histogram for the y values in each bin.  I then plot all the histograms for each of the bins on the same plot (preferably in different colors) to see more clearly how the distributions change as X changes.

NOTE: 1) the data is set on a log scale, hence logspace bins.
2) for the sake of argument, pretend that logicleHist is just a regular hist function.

EXAMPLE

```css
%DensPlot Slicer
data=[BFP GFP];
dp_bins=10;
dp_bounds=logspace(1,5,dp_bins);

%bins
b1=data(data(:,1) >= dp_bounds(1) & data(:,1) < dp_bounds(2),:);
b2=data(data(:,1) >= dp_bounds(2) & data(:,1) < dp_bounds(3),:);
b3=data(data(:,1) >= dp_bounds(3) & data(:,1) < dp_bounds(4),:);
b4=data(data(:,1) >= dp_bounds(4) & data(:,1) < dp_bounds(5),:);
b5=data(data(:,1) >= dp_bounds(5) & data(:,1) < dp_bounds(6),:);
b6=data(data(:,1) >= dp_bounds(6) & data(:,1) < dp_bounds(7),:);
b7=data(data(:,1) >= dp_bounds(7) & data(:,1) < dp_bounds(8),:);
b8=data(data(:,1) >= dp_bounds(8) & data(:,1) < dp_bounds(9),:);
b9=data(data(:,1) >= dp_bounds(9) & data(:,1) < dp_bounds(10),:);

figure;
hold on
logicleHist(b1(:,2));
logicleHist(b2(:,2));
logicleHist(b3(:,2));
logicleHist(b4(:,2));
logicleHist(b5(:,2));
logicleHist(b6(:,2));
logicleHist(b7(:,2));
logicleHist(b8(:,2));
logicleHist(b9(:,2));
```

Suggestions?  Thanks!

Comment: The For loop suggested by both @LordHenryWotton and dave kielpinski is exactly what I needed. The colors will have to wait, as your answers demonstrated that to modify color, the option must be included in the plotting function.  [logicleHist](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/35977-logicle-histogram/content/logicleHist.m) is a bi-exponential 'trace' plot that accommodates negative data, and I'll have to tweak the function to include a color modifier.  In the meantime, a subplot will do nicely.  You guys are awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question right, you want to histogram y's (or `data(:,2)`) that correspond to 10 bins of x (or `data(:,1)`). Please see the code below and refer to commented code and SO for further explanation on the code.

```
% The following are custom-created to make the code self-contained, replace with 
% your data and bounds.
data(:,1)=rand(100,1);
data(:,2)=rand(100,1);
dp_bounds=logspace(min(data(:,1)),max(data(:,1)),10);
data(:,1)=10.^rand(100,1);

figure('Position',[10 10 800 750],'Color','w');
bar_color=colormap;
bar_color=bar_color(linspace(1,size(colormap,1),numel(dp_bounds)),:); % Select colors per bar
for ii=1:numel(dp_bounds)-1
    sel_data=data(data(:,1) >= dp_bounds(ii) & data(:,1) < dp_bounds(ii+1),2);
    subplot(numel(dp_bounds)-1,1,ii);
    [h,bins_y]=hist(sel_data);
    bar(bins_y,h,'FaceColor', bar_color(ii,:)); % Bar plot with y histograms (auto bins for y)
    title(['x from ',num2str(dp_bounds(ii)),' to ',num2str(dp_bounds(ii+1))],'FontSize', 12)
end
```

If you copy and paste the code above to the Matlab prompt, you should see something similar to the following figure. [image]

**Update**: the code above was tested on Matlab 2010. If using the 2014 version, you may have to replace:

```
[h,bins_y]=hist(sel_data);
bar(bins_y,h,'FaceColor', bar_color(ii,:));
```

with `histogram(sel_data,'FaceColor', bar_color(ii,:))` (note the lack of a semi-colon) as observed in another solution.

Comment: I cannot see the reason to turn ``dp_bounds=logspace(1,5,dp_bins);`` into ``linspace(min(x(:,1)), max(x(:,1)),bins)`` as the user clearly knows he wants ``dp_bins=10`` bins (not 5 bins) and also he doesn't want them to be equally (linear) spaced, but log spaced.

Comment: @Nras, thanks for the note, in fact I got it wrong first place, but I think I now know what the OP wanted and I rewrote the solution.

Answer (score 1):

The first step might be to use a for loop. Replace everything in your code after

```
%bins
```

with

```
figure
hold on
for i = 1:(dp_bins-1)
     b = data(data(:,1)>=dp_bounds(i) & data(:,2)<=dp_bounds(i+1),:)
     hist(b(:,2))
end
```

where `b` is playing the role of your `b1`, `b2`, ... in turn. Note `histogram` is the currently used function in the latest release of Matlab. I only have `hist` myself.

Note that you can assign the second index to `b` in a single statement. I would normally write

```
b = data(data(:,1)>=dp_bounds(i) & data(:,2)<=dp_bounds(i+1),2)
histogram(b)
```

If you want to overlay so many histograms, I think the plot will get very hard to read no matter what you do with the colors. It's also quite difficult to control the histogram colors with `hist`. I'd suggest using stem plots, rather than histograms, for each of the `b`s. This would require another manual binning step over each `b`, which you could accomplish with a nested `for` loop.

Comment: works perfectly.  The [logicleHist](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/35977-logicle-histogram/content/logicleHist.m) function i'm using is a smoothened trace, so it would be easily visible in different colors, but I've learned that it will require some tweaking to add a color modifier.